# Anime where a boy is transported to a world with a different sun and enrolls in a magic school?

Tags: trinity-seven

I can't think of the anime name but the first episode stars the main character and either his little sister or female childhood friend. The main character can't help but notice that the sun is different (I think he noticed that the sun was black instead of orange or yellow). Then, I think, he is transported, or something similar to transported, to another world or dimension that's the same as earth but with magic. He then decides to enroll in a magic school because of a girl that may or may not have saved him.

I do remember that it is a recently dubbed or at least somewhat recently dubbed anime.

I only saw the first episode and would like to finish it but I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The show you are looking for is probably [Trinity Seven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_Seven).

[image]

Kasuga Arata lived a normal life together with his childhood friend, Hijiri Kasuga, in a small town. However, everything changed on the day of the Black Sun, and a magus (mage) appeared before him. The Black Sun caused the Breakdown Phenomenon which destroyed the town where he lives. Because of this, his normal life was artificially reconstructed by a grimoire that his childhood friend had left. The appearance of the magus led him to a new life in the Royal Biblia Academy and meeting the members of the Trinity Seven.

Comment: it was trinity seven. thanks guys. i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The anime that you are asking about is Trinity seven. It's first season has ended.

Description:

> Everyday is a normal day in the small town where Kasuga Arata lives;
>   however, everything changed on the day of the Black Sun, and following
>   it, a magician appears before him. The Black Sun caused the Breakdown
>   Phenomenon which destroyed the town where he lives.

Comment: Please don't link sites hosting unlicensed content.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know that.Thanks for letting me know.